# printing out data from ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

So this is the first time ive used ajax with rails, Ive managed to get the "data" back from the controller... how do i now print this out on the page? Im finding information on ajax online but 9 cant find any code the same as mine to reference?

The code changes the order in which details are displayed ASC to DESC.

JS FILE

```
  $(".ord-dir-link").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        url: '/index_list',
        method: 'get',
        data: jQuery.param({
        option: this.href.split("=")[2],
        direction: $('.list-direction').val()
        }),
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        success: function(data){
          console.log(data)
        }
      })
  });
```

CONTROLLER

```
    def index_list
      if params[:option]
        @products = @products.order("#{params[:option]} #{params[:direction]}")
        respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render json: @products.to_json }
        end
      end
    end
```

AND THE VIEW

```
    <div class="right-content">
      <table class="index-list">
        <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th><%= link_to "Name", index_list_path(option: "product_name"), class: "ord-dir-link"%></th>
          <th><%= link_to "Type", index_list_path(option: "type_of_product"), class: "ord-dir-link" %></th>
          <th><%= link_to "Section", index_list_path(option: "section"), class: "ord-dir-link" %></th>
          <th><%= link_to "Category", index_list_path(option: "category"), class: "ord-dir-link" %></th>
          <th><%= link_to "Price", index_list_path(option: "price"), class: "ord-dir-link" %></th>
          <th><%= link_to "Discount", index_list_path(option: "discount"), class: "ord-dir-link" %></th>
          <th><%= link_to "Views", index_list_path(option: "click_counter"), class: "ord-dir-link" %></th>
          <th><%= link_to "Upvotes", index_list_path(option: "upvotes"), class: "ord-dir-link" %></th>
          <th><%= select_tag(:direction, options_for_select([ ['ASC', "ASC"], ['DESC', "DESC"]] ), {:class => 'list-direction'})  %></th>
        </tr>
        <% n = 1 %>
        <% @products.each do |x| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%=n%>.</td>
          <td><%=x.product_name%></td>
          <td><%=x.type_of_product%></td>
          <td><%=x.section%></td>
          <td><%=x.category%></td>
          <td>£<%=x.price%></td>
          <td><%=x.discount if x.discount != nil%></td>
          <td><%=x.click_counter%></td>
          <td><%=x.upvotes%></td>
          <td><%=link_to "View", product_path(x.id)%></td>
          <% n += 1 %>
          <%end%>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Do i need to append the whole thing written out in javascript? it seems kind of long and clunky way to do it.

Comment: If you're response is html, then yeah.  You'd set it where ever on the page it should go with either `html()` or `append()`.

Comment: Did you get this sorted out?

Comment: @jvillian No,  i tried just dont quite understand how to access just the parts that i wanted,when rendering html i was getting the whole page returned to me. Then my laptop broke just got it back today

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on what Taplar said, you would do something like:

```
$(".ord-dir-link").on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: '/index_list',
      method: 'get',
      data: jQuery.param({
      option: this.href.split("=")[2],
      direction: $('.list-direction').val()
      }),
      contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
      success: function(data){
        $('#some-selector').html(data)
      }
    })
});
```

Comment: Hi @jvillian, i added an id = 'test' to the div class="right-content" then  doing $('#test').html(data) unfortunatly is doing apart from deleting the div completley?

Comment: "unfortunately is doing apart from"  ... what? @johnseymour

Comment: sorry missed a couple of words, 'unfortunately isnt doing anything apart from'

Comment: When you do `console.log(data)`, you see valid HTML? Try `append(data)` (although I'm confused by `html(data)` doesn't work).

Comment: data its not valid html, it comes back as an array, this here =>  (9) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

Comment: OOOOOOOhhh!!! Now I see what you were asking. Well, in your controller, you're rendering JSON. So, sure, you're getting JSON. (Duh, I should have seen that. Sorry.) So, in your controller, render HTML (using a partial, probably) instead of JSON. And then do the `.html(data)` thing.